# Limit movement using pathfinding navigation Godot

Tags: navigation, path-finding, godot

I want to limit the distance that my character can walk by the number of movements available

As I drag the mouse, a path finding line is drawn showing the path to be followed.when I click, the character follows the path, that is working fine.

How do I limit the distance to the a variable.

Code so far

```
func _process(delta): # executes the pathfinding
    var direction = Vector3()
    var step_size = delta * SPEED
    if can_move:
        get_parent().get_node("Draw").visible = false
        curr_state = "moving"
        var destination = path[0]
        direction = destination - character.translation
        if step_size > direction.length():
            step_size = direction.length()
            path.remove(0)
        if path.size() <=0:
            can_move = false
            curr_state = "idle"
        character.translation += direction.normalized() * step_size
        print(character.translation.direction_to(destination))
        direction.y = 0
        if direction:
            var look_at_point = character.translation + direction.normalized()
            character.look_at(look_at_point, Vector3.UP)


func _unhandled_input(event): 
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion and curr_state == "idle":
        path = navi.get_simple_path(character.translation, mouse_catcher(event), true)
        draw_path(path, mouse_catcher(event))
        get_parent().get_node("Draw").visible = true
    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_confirm") and curr_state =="idle":
        can_move = true



func mouse_catcher(event):
    var from = $Camera.project_ray_origin(event.position)
    var to = from + $Camera.project_ray_normal(event.position) * 10000
    var target_point = get_parent().get_node("Navi").get_closest_point_to_segment(from, to)
    return target_point


func draw_path(path_array, target_point, visi = true):
    var im = get_parent().get_node("Draw")
    if visi:
        im.visible = true
    else: 
        im.visible = false
    im.set_material_override(m)
    im.clear()
    im.begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_POINTS, null)
    im.add_vertex(path_array[0])
    im.add_vertex(path_array[path_array.size() - 1])
    im.end()
    im.begin(Mesh.PRIMITIVE_LINE_STRIP, null)
    print(path_array)
    for x in path:
        im.add_vertex(x)
    im.end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you want to limit the character movement

You have a variable `step_size` which holds how much the character moved on the frame. You can accumulate them to have how much the character has moved in total:

```
character.translation += direction.normalized() * step_size
total_walked = total_walked + step_size
```

*Declare `total_walked` with initial value of `0`.*

You can check if that total will exceed the amount you want the character to move, and if that is the case, don't move:

```
if total_walked + step_size < maximum:
    character.translation += direction.normalized() * step_size
    total_walked = total_walked + step_size
```

*Declare `maximum` with some value that makes sense for your case.*

And, of course, you would have to reset the accumulated value (`total_walked = 0`) when you want to allow the character to move again (perhaps you want to change `maximum` too).

---

You may or may not limit the last move to make sure the character moved exactly the maximum:

```
if total_walked + step_size >= maximum:
    step_size = maximum - total_walked

character.translation += direction.normalized() * step_size
total_walked = total_walked + step_size
```

---

### If you want to limit the length of the path

The path you get is a list of points. You can iterate over them and get the distance:

```
var total:float = 0.0
for index in path.size() - 1
    var a:Vector3 = path[index]
    var b:Vector3 = path[index + 1]
    var step:float = a.distance_to(b)
    total = total + step
```

*I'm assuming these are `Vector3`, given that you are raycasting.*

You truncate as soon as that goes over the maximum:

```
var total:float = 0.0
for index in path.size() - 1
    var a:Vector3 = path[index]
    var b:Vector3 = path[index + 1]
    var step:float = a.distance_to(b)
    total = total + step
    if total > maximum:
        path.resize(index)
        break
```

---

You may or may not want to insert a point at the end to make sure the distance is exactly the maximum:

```
var total:float = 0.0
for index in path.size() - 1
    var a:Vector3 = path[index]
    var b:Vector3 = path[index + 1]
    var step:float = a.distance_to(b)
    if total + step >= maximum:
        path.resize(index)
        path.append(a + a.direction_to(b) * (maximum - total))
        break

    total = total + step
```

Comment: path.append(a.direction_to(b) * selected_pawn.max_ap - total)  

ERROR: Invalid operands 'Vector3' and 'float' in operator '-'.

at this line `path.append(a.direction_to(b) * selected_pawn.max_ap - total) `

Comment: I don't know if there is a error, but I removed the total  from the line that return an error
and when I click to move then, the path is drawn correctly but the pawn moves in a straight line towards the end point ignoring the navmesh

Comment: @JacobAthias That's on me, I forgot operator precedence. Fixed the answer. - I think, without total, it is removing all the points from the path and appending a single point. Have it edit the path you draw, so you see what it is doing.

Comment: Solved. But my pawn is still walking on a straight line, ignoring navmesh
The movements are a being restricted, but Drawn Path is still drawing as fas as the mouse go.

I tested the navmesh without your code and it works fine

Comment: direction_to() is returning a point close to the origin of the whole scene. Is that intentional?
@Theraot

Comment: @JacobAthias looks like I had a big lapsus that day. Yes, should be a director vector, of length 1. And that vector is scaled when it is multiplied by a float. However, I should add the first vector back. Edit: Answer fixed, I think. Unless I missed something else.

Comment: THHHHHHANNNNNNNNNNKKKKKKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS